# average score of students

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i am a little confused and please help me to figure out how to solve such questions

[image]

i know that it could be solved using ven diagram,but i could not  get any correct intersection,now what i have tried,  if question one  solved correctly by $200$ and question $2$  is solved by $304$,in total it is $504$,which means that $4$  solved both,so total ssore would be  $196*25+4*50+296*25$,but  what about third and fourth question?if we do it separately,we get that $100 $ person sold both $3$ and $4$,so only $3$ and $4$ was solved by $250$ and $150$,in total we have $196+4+296+250+150=896$,does it means that  from these  students  all question was done by $896-400=496$?please help me

Comment: Score for each answer is mutually exclusive from score for other answers - therefor no point putting in a Venn diagram - no intersections indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of points scored on the exam would be $200 * 25 + 304 * 25 + 350 * 25 + 250 * 25 = 27,600$, out of a maximum possible $400 * (25 * 4) = 40,000$.

Taking $\frac{27,600}{40,000}$ and simplifying it gives $\frac{276}{400} = \frac{69}{100}$.
As there are $100$ total points on the exam, each student scored, on average, $\frac{69}{100} * 100 = 69$ points.

Comment: but some of them  got more then 25 right?

Comment: Yes, some people will have scored more than 25 points. I'm not sure if I'm really understanding what you're trying to ask here... How many students answered a given subset of questions doesn't really matter, since to find the average, all that is needed is the total number of points scored and the total number of possible points.

Comment: aaa i see,if it would be  given  $200$ solved $1$,$300$  second  and  for example  $50$ both,this does not matter?

Comment: Yes. Which students solve which problem are irrelevant. With that particular example, there have to be at least 100 students solving both, but whether there are 100, 150, or 200 will not change the average score.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to do any calculation to get the answer. This can be just estimated.

- 4 Questions with 25 points each is max 100 points.
- 400 students answering 4 questions - 200 ~ 350 gets each answer right.

Average must be between 50 and 100.

Only **D** fits the estimation range